# How to install Magento with Azure and how to see all code file with Azure

Tags: magento2

Is any one have experience about Azure with magento.
How to install Magento with Azure and how to see all code file with Azure
I am new to Docker and Kubernetes and I want to install magento2 with docker images on Azure server.
Any One know about this how it will work.

Comment: What exactly does not work? Could you add more details?

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau: I updated my question.

Comment: if you read a little interface messages and docs, setup something, probably fail few times. then when you install on 5th time - your shop will work.